# Importing images from URL in excel, storing them in the file itself

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am using the VBA code bellow to import images from URLs to my excel and store them to the file itself. The problem I can't solve is that they maintain their aspect ratio, but they do not show centered in my cells and I have to resize them all every time. Any suggestions?

````
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim Filename As String

Sub URLPictureInsert()
    Dim theShape As Shape
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCol As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("F2:F500")
    For Each cell In rng
        Filename = cell
        Set theShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture( _
            Filename:=Filename, linktofile:=msoFalse, _
            savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, _
            Left:=cell.Left, Top:=cell.Top, Width:=-1, Height:=-1)
        If theShape Is Nothing Then GoTo isnill
        With theShape
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            .Top = cell.Top - 1
            .Left = cell.Left - 1
            .Height = cell.Height - 1
            .Width = cell.Width - 1
        End With
        cell.ClearContents
isnill:
        Set theShape = Nothing
        Range("f2").Select

    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Debug.Print "Done " & Now

End Sub```
````

Answer (score 1):

Welcome!

After setting `.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue`, there is no need to change both parameters - both height and width. Change, for example, the height - the width of the image will change automatically. Check if such a wide image fits in the cell. If not, then change the width and the height will decrease even more. And now align what happened in the middle of the cell. Try replacing the `With theShape...End With` code block with this snippet:

```
        With theShape
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            .Height = cell.Height - 2
            If .Width > cell.Width Then
                .Width = cell.Width - 2
            End If
            .Top = cell.Top + 1
            .Left = cell.Left + (cell.Width - .Width) / 2
        End With
```

Comment: Thank you very much JohnSun! This worked fine...